# iOS: saving nsmutablearray for user

Tags: ios

I have looked into a few posts and saw some related posts on it but I still don't get it.

My app is a rating system. I want to store which posts the user rated so he/she can't rate again. Each post has an ID. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rating is happening locally, you should look into [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) to store your Post objects along with the user rating. You could then query the store using the post id to see whether it's been rated already.

A more lightweight approach (although I wouldn't recommend it) would be to save the rating directly to NSUserDefaults using a unique key, containing the post id. For example:

```
NSNumber *rating = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8];
NSString *postKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"post_%i", post_id];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:rating forKey:postKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To know whether the user has already rated a post, you would do so with:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:postKey] == nil)
   // post has not been rated
```

Comment: shouldnt this be an array and not a string? the user will rate multiple posts

Comment: The way I did it, you save the NSNumber value of the post rating under a post-specific key containing the post_id (for instance "post_34"). One NSNumber per post.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple store the post id and rating in either database or in nsuserdefaults and check if the id is already rated restrict user to rate again.